# Finding a limit if it is almost surely or in probability

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\overset{\text{i.i.d}}{\sim}\exp{(\lambda)}$. Find 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}T_k^2.
$$
*solution:* First, if I show that it converges almost surely, I will get that it converges in probability. I'm able to use the WLLN or SLLN. In fact, if I just take 
$$
S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n T_k \Longrightarrow \frac{S_n}{n} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty } \mathbb{E}X_1=\frac{1}{\lambda} \quad \quad a.s.
$$
However, I don't know how I could proceed with the squares. Thanks so much for any idea/hint.

Answer (score 2):

$(T_k^{2})$ is also an i.i.d. sequence. So SLLN applies to this sequence and we see that $\frac  1 n  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} T_k^{2} \to ET_1^{2}$ almost surely.  I will leave it to you to compute $ET_1^{2}$ .

Comment: Thanks so much. It looks like $\mathbb{E} T_1^2=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$, is that right?

Comment: @CharlesSeife $ET_1^{2}=\frac 2 {\lambda^{2}}$.

Comment: I don't know how we get 2. I thought $E(T_1^2)=E(T_1)E(T_1)$ But I realized I'm wrong, computing directly $E(T_1^2)=\frac{2}{\lambda^2}$. I really appreciate it.